# How to Select Drop Down Menu in VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

Here is my VBA code I am new with this. Several time I tried to access to drop down menu 'My Tender' under Tabheader menu 'Tender' but I couldn't do it. I don't understand where I need to do correction for this...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim ele As HTMLElementCollection


    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "https://www.eprocure.gov.bd"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    doc.getElementById("txtEmailId").Value = "******"
    doc.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "******"
    doc.getElementById("btnLogin").Click



    For Each ele In doc.getElementByclassName("ddsubmenustyle")(0).getElementByTagName("a")
        If InStr(ele.href, "/tenderer/MyTenders.jsp") > 0 Then doc.navigate ele.href: Exit For
    Next ele



End Sub
```

Here is my HTML Code where I want to get my access ....

---

```
                <ul>

                    <li><a title="Home" href="/Index.jsp" id="headTabHomePage"><img alt="Home" src="/resources/images/Dashboard/HomeIcn.png">Home</a></li>


                    <li><a title="Message Box" href="/resources/common/InboxMessage.jsp" id="headTabMsgBox"><img alt="Message Box" src="/resources/images/Dashboard/msgBoxIcn.png">Message Box</a></li>
                    <li><a title="APP" href="#" rel="submenu-configuration" id="headTabApp" class=""><img alt="APP" src="/resources/images/Dashboard/AppIcn_1.png">APP</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Tender" href="#" rel="ddsubmenu2" id="headTabTender" **class="selected"><img alt="Tender" src="/resources/images/Dashboard/tenderIcn.png">Tender</a></li>
                    <li>**<a title="Doc. Library" href="#" rel="docMenu" id="headTabDocLib" class=""><img alt="Doc. Library" src="/resources/images/Dashboard/DocLib.gif">Doc. Library</a></li>


                </ul>
```

---

```
                <ul>

                <li><a href="/tenderer/TenderWatchList.jsp">Watch List</a></li>
                **<li><a href="/tenderer/MyTenders.jsp">My Tenders</a></li>**
                <li><a href="/tenderer/RestrictedTenders.jsp">Limited Tenders</a></li>
                <li><a href="/resources/common/AllTenders.jsp?h=f">All Tenders</a></li>

                <li><a href="/tenderer/JvcaList.jsp">Propose JVCA</a></li>

                     </ul>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
For Each ele In doc.getElementByclassName("ddsubmenustyle")(0).getElementByTagName("a")
    If InStr(ele.href, "/tenderer/MyTenders.jsp") > 0 Then doc.navigate ele.href: Exit For
Next ele
```

You can replace those lines with using an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selector with contains operator or even ends with operator i.e.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[href$='MyTenders.jsp']").click
```

Comment: I am new ... so would you please provide full code for me. I didn't understand where I actually need to do changes?

Comment: Please see edit and let me know if that is clearer.

Comment: No it didn't work ..would you please tell me what is the code for mouseover on menu and click in vba?

Comment: I suggest updating the question with all the relevant details and what you are trying to achieve.